# simctl recordVideo - problem streaming the video

Tags: xcode, xcrun, simctl

I want to be able to stream the booted simulator's screen to a video output. I know that simctl has a `recordVideo` option that supports streaming. I've tried the following command:

```
xcrun simctl io DEVICE_ID recordVideo --type=fmp4 tcp://127.0.0.1:9010
```

Which seems to correctly start a stream. But then, if I try to connect to the stream, e.g. with VLC, nothing happens.

The console outputs the following:

```
Using host address localhost.
Connected to client address at localhost.
```

but nothing is displayed in VLC. Am I doing something wrong?

It's very difficult to find any documentation for this, so any help is much appreciated

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @stoefln unfortunately not no

Comment: did you find another way to stream your screen?

Comment: I didn't no. Have you got any other solutions that have worked for you?

Comment: Not yet. Still investigating...